# Showing the sequence converges to the square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For any $a > 0$, I have to show the sequence $x_{n+1}=$  $ \frac 12\left(x_n+  \frac {a} {x_n}\right)$

converges to the square root of $a$ for any $x_1>0$.

If I assume the limit exists ( denoted by $x$) then,

$x= \frac 12\left(x+  \frac {a} {x}\right)$ can be solved to $x^2 = a$

How could I show that it does exist?

Comment: Try to show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded, then you can conclude that the limit exists.

Comment: It seemed that whether or not it increased/decreased depended on the value of $x_n$ compared to $a$ and to 1. I assumed this would mean I would have to break it into multiple cases. Is there something I missed?

Comment: we have that $x_n \geq a$ by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality for $n \geq 2$ so you may assume that $x_n > a$.

Comment: Look up Hero (Heron) of Alexandria, and also Newton's Method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we need to show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded.

First, we observe that
$$
x_n-x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac12\Bigl(x_n+\frac a{x_n}\Bigr)=\frac1{2x_n}(x_n^2-a).
$$
Secondly, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
x_n^2-a
 &=\frac14\Bigl(x_{n-1}+\frac a{x_{n-1}}\Bigr)^2-a\\
 &=\frac{x_{n-1}^2}4-\frac a2+\frac{a^2}{4x_{n-1}^2}\\
 &=\frac14\Bigl(x_{n-1}^2-2a+\frac{a^2}{x_{n-1}^2}\Bigr)\\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\Bigl(x_{n-1}-\frac a{x_{n-1}}\Bigr)^2\\
 &\ge0.
\end{align*}
Hence, $x_n\ge x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ is bounded from below since $x_n^2\ge a$ for each $n\ge2$.

Monotonic and bounded sequence converges. Denote the limit of the sequence $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Then we have that
$$
x=\frac12\Bigl(x+\frac ax\Bigr)\quad\iff\quad x=\sqrt a.
$$

Comment: This argument shows that *a* limit exists, but how does is show that the limit is $\sqrt{a}$?

Comment: @FlybyNight The OP stated that he/she already knows that the limit is $\sqrt a$ if it exists.

Comment: @FlybyNight I added the fact that the limit is $\sqrt a$ to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

That looks a lot like the well known method for computing square roots. It is derived by using Newton's on

$$ x^2 - a = 0 $$

$$ x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} $$

$$=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}\right) $$

If it converges it will converge to the $$ \sqrt{a} $$